# Change the initial state of ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I'm having trouble changing the initial state of `ExpandableListView`, I want it to appear "open" at first.

Comment: Is it not displayed as checked or does its inner state (`isChecked()`) remain `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend from SimpleExpandableListAdapter and override getGroupView:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
    mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did to solve my problem. Sorry for not posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to visualize the mark:

```
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

then use this to changing the initial state

```
    android:checked="true"
```

or this

```
    mCheckedTextView.setChecked(true);
```

Here my CheckedTextView:

```
    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />
```

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't make the children appear.

Comment: Apologies, I did mess, actually I'm using ExpandableListView, and I wanted to expand it by default. I edited my question.